# I want convert my dataframes into excel sheets but I got dataframe is too large error!1

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

This is my code.

Here My dataFrame is df and I am trying to convert this data frame into excel sheet.
I am using ExcelWriter to convert dataframe to Excel sheet

```
#python
    
dataxlsx=pd.ExcelWriter("FromPython.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
#dataxlsx.book.use_zip64()
df.to_excel(dataxlsx,sheet_name="df_sheet1")
dataxlsx.save()
```

so far I got the following

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-3d2ff9cdbba5> in <module>
      2 dataxlsx=pd.ExcelWriter("FromPython.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
      3 #dataxlsx.book.use_zip64()
----> 4 df.to_excel(dataxlsx,sheet_name="df_sheet1")
      5 dataxlsx.save()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2187             inf_rep=inf_rep,
   2188         )
-> 2189         formatter.write(
   2190             excel_writer,
   2191             sheet_name=sheet_name,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    801         num_rows, num_cols = self.df.shape
    802         if num_rows > self.max_rows or num_cols > self.max_cols:
--> 803             raise ValueError(
    804                 f"This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: {num_rows}, {num_cols} "
    805                 f"Max sheet size is: {self.max_rows}, {self.max_cols}"

ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 5704247, 5 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384
```

give me proper solution please

Comment: The excel data format restricts the number of rows per sheet. You can maybe subdivide the df and distribute over multiple sheets.

Comment: I want keep it in same sheet

Comment: Then you're out of luck as Microsoft have a limit on [Excel file sizes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: This is [not possible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: ohh atleast provide me code to limit rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your df.to_excel,please.xlsxwriter just write data to mem and flush into the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).